# Parse.com: Update of user table is not working

Tags: parse-platform

I have defined a cloud function to set custom column in User table. I have 6 results returned for my query but update of field only happens for 3 rows, I could not understand what's wrong with the code below,

```
Parse.Cloud.define("updateSaturdayAbsentWeeks", function(request, response) {
// User master key so that we can update all users
Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
// Tables to Query  
var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
// We want only players who are absent on Saturdays
query.equalTo("isSaturdayAbsent", true);
query.find({
    success: function(results) {    
        console.error('updateSaturdayAbsentWeeks, Saturday absent players count ' + results.length);
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) { 
            var absentUser = results[i];
            var absentWeeks = absentUser.get('saturdayAbsentWeeks') - 1;
            absentUser.set("saturdayAbsentWeeks", absentWeeks);
            absentUser.save();
            console.error('updateSaturdayAbsentWeeks, absentWeeks for user name = ' + absentUser.get('username') + ', is = ' + absentWeeks)
        }

        // All done
        response.success("updateSaturdayAbsentWeeks finished successfully");
    },
    error: function() {
        console.error("runSaturdayExpense, lookUp Failed - Each player enjoyed the game on Saturday ");
        response.error("updateSaturdayAbsentWeeks failed");
    }
});
});
```

After the query I can see it returned 6 records but in the for loop it only updates 3 records only and does not do anything to other three records and no errors returned.

Any pointers to understand why all 6 records are not getting updated would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has to do with the fact that the `save()` function is asynchronous. The proper way to do this is using `saveAll()`.

```
query.find({
    success: function(results) {
        var saveThese = []; 
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) { 
            var absentUser = results[i];
            var absentWeeks = absentUser.get('saturdayAbsentWeeks') - 1;
            absentUser.set("saturdayAbsentWeeks", absentWeeks);
            saveThese.push(absentUser);
        }
        Parse.Object.saveAll(saveThese, {
            success: function (list) {
                response.success("updateSaturdayAbsentWeeks finished successfully");
            }, 
            error: function (error) {
                response.error("did not save all the items");
            }
        });
    },
    error: function() {
        response.error("updateSaturdayAbsentWeeks failed");
    }
});
```